# Is there a 'soft' version of chroot(2)?

Tags: c, security, unix, system-calls

I'm wanting to use `chroot(2)` so that when `/file.txt` is accessed, the file at `/media/something/file.txt` is instead retrieved. I *could* append the path to `/media/something`, but that would allow for a file outside of the intended pseudo-root to be accessible like `/../../etc/passwd` going to `/etc/passwd`.

I've tried a lot of 'googling around' with no luck.

Comment: creating a symlink perhaps??

Comment: Resolving paths into proper absolute paths without `.` or `..` is a long solved problem. From that it's easy to see if they go out of the filesystem jail.